# How do I center a script?

Tags: javascript

The code I am having issues with is http://jsbin.com/ESOdELU/1/edit

I'm in the early process of learning Javascript and my last question was answered very well and I got the perfect script (linked above) for what I am trying to do but everytime I try and add things to the script it messes up so I clearly do not know what I am doing.

I now want to centrally align the script and I want to do a line break between a button and the data the button generates once pressed.

The code is currently between  and  and when I try and add code to align the script inside it doesn't work. When I try outside (I searched online and saw about using div align but that doesn't work for me either unfortunately).

For the line break I want to be able to have the button on the top line and on the bottom line I want the data to be displayed once the button has been pressed.

Comment: Post your code in your question please. Should jsbin be inaccessible then your question has no value to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div and center it:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;" id="someid"></div>
```

Then the last line of your Javascript where it says

```
wordRandomizer.run(document.body);
```

You can reference any element you want. In this case you would change it to:

```
wordRandomizer.run(document.getElementById("#someid"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to center the script and now I know for future reference so I highly appreciate the answer. Do you happen to know how to do the line break between the button and the generated data?

Comment: Style the button. In your CSS you could do `#someid button { display: block; }`

Comment: I tried adding that under the button but it broke again and the button disappeared. Where should I add it into the code?

Comment: That code is CSS. You need it either in an included stylesheet or between `<style></style>` tags. Mozilla's CSS tutorial page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tutorials